# Visual Studio 2015 crashes on ctrl+RR renaming

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash, rename, vcs-checkout

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. 
When I use CTRL+RR to refactor a class/method/argument name - VS crashes.
It happens when the refactoring involve checking out other files.
My settings of Options->Source Control->Environment->Checked-in items->Editing, are: Prompt for check out.

Comment: Any news on that? I experience the same problematic behavior.

Comment: Nothing that I know of...